# Vimeo API upload video and bypass temp file on the server

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm using the Vimeo API to create an upload interface on my website. However, the standard example here https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/videos/upload requires the file to be uploaded via a temp file on my server. Unfortunately, the size of file I can upload is limited by the php ini settings to 20mb (editing the php ini file is not permitted with my hosting package).

After searching on here, all the examples I can find appear to use the same method and require `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']` - tmp_name being the temporary file created on my server when uploading - which fails if the file is larger than 20mb.

Is it even possible to upload directly from client (desktop or mobile device) to vimeo's server? If it is, can someone point me in the direction of an example or guides?

Comment: There is no way where you can bypass this. PHP will always store uploaded file into a temporary storage for processing after that it's up to the dev to move it to permanent location or upload it to some other place.

Comment: For your problem of file size, either increase the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in `php.ini` file or else by implementing file chunk upload, that splits the upload into smaller pieces an assembling these pieces when the upload is completed

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Looks like it is not possible so I ended up changing hosting provider to one that allowed 100mb upload_max_filesize